# Logically combining multiple IFs

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Col H should display "Yes" if the value of Col F is greater than 25.

If the value of Col F is less than 25 but not blank or "-", Col H should show "No".

If Col F is blank or "-", Col H should be blank.

I have tried this formula however the result is False.

```
=IF(F9="-","-",IF(F9>25,"Yes",IF(G9="Yes","No",IF(F9<25,"No"))))
```

How can I combine these multiple criteria into a single Google Sheets formula?

[image: Image of spreadsheet]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to check out the guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your question accordingly--especially showing what you have tried, and what previous answers you have found that do not suit your question. What you are looking for is [`IFS`; see the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en)

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Post has been updated

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in column H and paste this in H4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F4:F), 
              IF(F4:F="-", ,
              IF(F4:F >= 25, "Yes", 
              IF((F4:F < 25)*(F4:F<>""), "No", ))), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: it didn't work on my end. I did everything in column H except header. The result was #REF!